# Check if <li> is present

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a `<ul> <li>` list that im extracting data from, but the `<li>`'s numbers are dynamic based on the site.

This is my code;

```
HtmlNode dordunculi = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='InfoList']/li[4]/span");
```

How can i check if `/li[4]` exist before doing something, I know that I need to use `contains` but couldnt figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `SelectSingleNode()` returns value before doing further processing, for example :

```
HtmlNode dordunculi = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='InfoList']/li[4]/span");
if(dordunculi)
{
    //do something with `dordunculi`
    Console.WriteLine(dordunculi.InnerText);
}
```

Or, using C# 6.0, you can use convinient null-propagation operator :

```
Console.WriteLine(dordunculi?.InnerText);
```

Notice that XPath simply returns empty in case no element match the entire XPath. For example, `/li[4]/span` simply returns empty in case `li[4]` is not found, no risk of getting NRE. So if you don't have specific intention doing the check but to avoid NRE, you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks @har07 didnt test it, tought it will give an error because it wont find it.